# I need to add new menu item inside the custom post admin menu

Tags: taxonomy

in my site i have at least 5 diferent custom posts that im using pods to create them, inside each admin menu i need to create a item that opens a thickbox, with a iframe for a external link, create the thickbox is not a issue, but to create the menu ites is.
How do i do that?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation on the function [add_submenu_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/)

You should be able to add as many links as you need given the parent post type.